# Django form outputting the default field value every time

Tags: python, django

Here's my model/form:

```
class AdvertisePost(Post):
    position = models.IntegerField(default=DURATION_CHOICES[2][0], choices=DURATION_CHOICES)
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=48)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class AdvertisePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    position = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, required=False, choices=DURATION_CHOICES)
    duration = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type':'range', 'step': '1', 'min': '1', 'max': '148'}), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AdvertisePost
        fields = [
            ...
            'position',
            'duration'
        ]
```

**views**

```
def options(request):
    options_form = AdvertisePostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if options_form.is_valid():
        instance = options_form.save(commit=False)
        print(instance.duration) #prints 8 every time (default value)
        print(instance.position) #prints 48 every time (default value)

    context = {
        'options_form': options_form
    }

    return render(request, 'advertising/options.html', context)
```

and my **template**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ options_form.position }}
    {{ options_form.duration }}
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Even though I change the values it outputs the same default value every time. Any idea why this is and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which
>   accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False,
>   then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the
>   database. In this case, it’s up to you to call save() on the resulting
>   model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on
>   the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the
>   specialized model saving options. commit is True by default.

You are getting an instance with your defaults values. 
Look it better in [Django Docs - Save Method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: I use `commit=False` in another view and it works fine (doesn't output the default). I removed `commit=False` anyway to check if it works and it still outputs the default value.